# kvm - Recover domain from .img file alone

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

Yesterday I had a drive failure (raid-0) in the host system and had to re-install the os. Fortunately the vps images were on another raid array (raid-5) and the .img files are still available. However when I try to run one of the images, virsh complains that the domain doesn't exist, which makes sense as it was never registered by way of `virsh-install`. So my question is; is it possible to register the img file with virsh so I can start the vps as I did before the hard-drive failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is create a new VM (domain) and use the old .img as it's hard drive. It would be a good thing to set  it up with all the old settings, especially the old MAC used by the lost VM

If the VM definition XML files are also intact, you can re-register them with `virsh define VM.XML`

Comment: The vm wasn't lost, it's available, and theoretically so are all the settings contained within the vm. All I need to do is issue the `virsh start domain` command and it should work as if nothing ever happened. I just don't know how to re-register the .img file with virsh.

Comment: please see the added edit

Comment: Although this answer lacks a demonstration, it is technically correct. Thanks. Took some research to figure out exactly where the configs reside, how to rebuild, and how to hook into them, but it did work.